# Why aren't commands from the Dockerfile executed when the `/bin/bash` command is appended to `docker run -it IMAGE ID`?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am just starting out with Docker. I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jonathonf/manjaro 

CMD ["pacman", "-S", "--noconfirm", "git"]
```

When I build the image with

```
sudo docker build -t uname/description:tag  .
```

and then run it with

```
sudo docker run IMAGE_ID
```

, where `IMAGE_ID` is the ID I get from `sudo docker images` command, the command in the Dockerfile `CMD ["pacman", "-S", "--noconfirm", "git"]` runs, git is installed, a container is created (that I can commit).

If I run the image with

```
sudo docker run IMAGE_ID /bin/bash
```

the `CMD` from the Dockerfile is not executed.

I expected it to run the commands from the Dockerfile, make `git` available in the container and let me work further in the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things here:

1. If you want git installed always, why run it as a `CMD` and then manually commit as a new image, rather than just running in a Dockerfile `RUN` instruction?
2. Anything you put after `docker run...` is going to run *as* the `CMD` and override it. If you don't want to override it, you should put it as an `ENTRYPOINT` instead. But really you should do 1.

Comment: I see I need to go back to the documentation.  To answer the question: I thought that this is the way I can incrementally write the Dockerfile. The software I want to put into a container has many dependencies and is complicated to build, I can't write a Dockerfile for it from scratch. I was thinking I could execute the steps in a container and then append stuff to the Dockerfile, then build the image with the new Dockerfile, log in with bash, check everything works + repeat.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `CMD ["pacman", "-S", "--noconfirm", "git"]` in your dockerfile, you are setting `pacman -S --noconfirm git` as [pid-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) process of your container.

Now when you run container `sudo docker run IMAGE_ID` the first process will be the one specified in the CMD. You can verify this by running `docker exec -it container-id ps -ef`

When you run `sudo docker run IMAGE_ID /bin/bash` the pid-1 process of your docker container is replaced by `/bin/bash`.

```
[user@jumphost ~]$ docker run -itd -p 3666:3306 alpine sh
dcef6d1cc121bfd195552fa7639038ac513a74eaa035a855bb7917dd620be642
[user@jumphost ~]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
dcef6d1cc121        alpine              "sh"                2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3666->3306/tcp   fervent_euclid
[user@jumphost ~]$ docker exec -it dcef6d1cc121 ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sh
    7 root      0:00 ps -ef
[user@jumphost ~]$
```

Also to know more about `CMD` check [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) out.

Also check docker [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and its [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) with CMD.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how Docker works. You override the CMD from your Dockerfile. If you want to achive both, a git Install and your bash command, move your CMD command to RUN command. Please consider Dockerfile documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run